# check eval() error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have made a calculator using html css Javascript, I came through so many input problems, so to calculate the result ( '=' ) I used the function eval(), I want to know what does it return exactly and how to spot errors and fix them, for example : typing ***/+6 and clicking on the '=', will do nothing, I want to display an error message, I tried try-catch but it didn't work :

```
function res() { 
    var r=eval(document.getElementById("_input").textContent); 
    try{ 
        eval(document.getElementById("_input").textContent);        
    }   
    catch(error){   
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML="Error"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: any error displayed in console?

Comment: eval returns the result of the expression passed to it, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!

Comment: @HiteshKansagara Yes : SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i tried it , no errors in console , but the error message is not displaying in the calculator screen

Comment: var r=eval(document.getElementById("_input").textContent); remove this sentence or take it into try block then execute code may be it will catched

Comment: 'function res()
{
 try{
 var r=eval(document.getElementById("_input").textContent);
  eval(document.getElementById("_input").textContent);
 }
 catch(error)
 {
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML="Error";
 }
 console.log("goood");
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML="= "+r;
}'   i tried this , it starts to show "Undifined" when clicking "=" after an invalid input , but why does'nt it show "Error" written in catch , and when i input  a number that bagins with 0 and clicking "=" it shows a different result , like 047 = 39

Comment: share your html and js code